# ActionBarSherlock raises Exception

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem with implementing `ActionBarSherlock` in my test application.

If the main Activity is a subclass of `Activity` everything works perfectly, but when I subclass `SherlockActivity` I get an exception:

```
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pl.lsi.test.packages/pl.lsi.test.packages.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.lsi.test.packages.MainActivity
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.lsi.test.packages.MainActivity
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
12-13 11:33:02.630: E/AndroidRuntime(11345):    ... 11 more
```

I also have a problem with applying `SherlockTheme` to the manifest (Sherlock styles is not visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then in values folder you have to add styles in styles.xml file....
 I think you are missing the some file to place there

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I have to add all resources from ActionSherlockBar project to my own project. Then I was able to apply style and Exception is not raised any more